# Codeigniter3 ,Profile picture not displaying using session

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

Good Day,
image successfully upload in my database and folder, but when I tried to session image not displaying ,I do always fetching and image display but in my session it not displaying I don't know what's wrong thanks for answer.

upload path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2RKu.png)

**view**

```
 <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           <img  src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$this->session->userdata('profilepicture')?>"  width="150" height="100">
          <span class="d-none d-md-inline"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('full_name');?></span>
        </a>
```

**login controller and session**
my fullname session is displaying but if I try to my profile picture no image display

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
      }
    

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    
    public function auth(){
       
        $username = $this->input->post('username',TRUE);
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password',TRUE));
        $validate = $this->Login_model->validate($username,$password);
        
        if($validate->num_rows() > 0){
            $data     = $validate->row_array();
            $name     = $data['full_name'];
            $user_id  = $data['id'];
            $username = $data['username'];
            $position = $data['position'];
            $profilepicture= $data['profilepicture'];
            $sesdata  = array(
                'full_name'     => $name,
                'user_id'       =>$user_id,
                'username'      => $username,
                'position'      => $position,
                'profilepicture'=> $profilepicture,
                'logged_in'     => TRUE
            );


            
            $this->session->set_userdata($sesdata);
            

            // access login for admin
            if($position === '1'|'2'){
                redirect('dashboard');
            }
            // access login for account specialist
            elseif($position === '3'){
                redirect('dashboard/asdep');
            }
            // access login for Account (sales/finance/v-tech)
            elseif($position === '4'|'5'|'6'){
                redirect('dashboard/dept');
            }               
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "No account found in Database. Please Try Again.");
            redirect('login');
        }
      }

      function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url("login"));
    }

}
```

**model**for login page

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model{

  
  function validate($username,$password){
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $result = $this->db->get('users',1);
    return $result;
  }
  
  function active($id){
      $this->db->where('id',$id);
      $query = $this->db->get('users');
      if($query){
          return $query->row();
          
      }
  }

}
```

**database**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profilepicture` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**my data**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `full_name`, `username`, `password`, `position`, `profilepicture`) VALUES
(7, 'Jhon', 'jhon@gmail.com', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 3, 'profile.png');
```

Comment: Paste the code in your `Login_model.php` in your question so we can help you debug properly.

Comment: done adding model.

Comment: Whats the value of $this->session->userdata('profilepicture')? If that is correct and its the same as the image name then you might want to check the path you're using in your img.

Comment: Can you please the Image Path?

Comment: my upload path already added please check..

Comment: [`$this->load->library('session');`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class) ?

Comment: already set in my autoload.